# When was manual dynamic memory managment introduced?

Tags: reference-request, operating-systems, memory-management, history

Original Fortran only had static memory. Algol introduced stack allocation. Lisp had Garbage Collection. But when where manual dynamic memory management such as in C introduced.

In C memory can be manually allocated and deallocated with `malloc` and `free`. Was this the first instance of this method of memory management in a programing language?

Comment: Is the question "when did a mainstream lanugage emerge that had X" or "when was X first discussed in the literature"? Because the former is offtopic here.